# How to generate documentation for modules that are behind #[cfg(test)]?

Tags: testing, rust, documentation, rust-cargo

In a Rust project there is a module with utilities to support testing, packed in a module `test_utils`:

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod test_utils;
```

Is there a way to make `cargo doc` generate also the documentation for `test_utils` module and the things inside?

Comment: Because the obvious way results in no docs because of the conditional compilation?

Comment: It's default behavior, yes. Unlike `cargo check --tests`, there is no --tests option for `cargo doc`.
I'd assume that `#[cfg(test)]` just enables `test` feature, but `cargo doc --features test` compains, that feature `test` does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably multiple ways of generating documentation for tests, but I think the easier approach is to generate the documentation with `cargo rustdoc` and pass the `--cfg test` flag through:

```
cargo rustdoc -- --cfg test
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!
I was not aware of `cargo rustdoc` cause it's not shown  by `cargo --help`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `#[cfg(any(test, doc))]` is probably not enough, it will generate doc with no function information.

```rust
/// The module should work
#[cfg(any(test, doc))]
pub mod test_utils {

    /// The function about test1
    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        assert!(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

In order to doc with  utilities to support testing, perhaps `[cfg_attr(not(doc), test)]` is necessary.

```rust
/// The module should work
#[cfg(any(test, doc))]
pub mod test_utils {

    /// The function about test1
    #[cfg_attr(not(doc), test)]
    fn test1() {
        assert!(true);
    }
}
```

After added `[cfg_attr(not(doc), test)]` above test cases:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found that this works too:

```rs
#[cfg(any(test, doc))]
pub mod test_utils;
```

While documentation is generated with regular

```
cargo doc
```